# iOS Video upload to Facebook - error but success

Tags: ios, facebook

This code perfectly worked for me few days ago. But now I'm getting

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

error but the video is successfully uploaded. Has anyone face this issues before ? What might be the issue here ?

My code is

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:video_file_location];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, _videoFileName],
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"iOS app title", @"title",
                               @"my description", @"description",
                               nil];

[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
 parameters:params
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"FB error - %@", [error localizedDescription]);

 }];
```

And I get permission with

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                     }];
```

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug on facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/247807142061930?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52d4393364f528e07526347

Comment: Thanks. There FB has set the priority to Medium. So can't expect a solution soon. :(